# How do you create hyperlinks with a database using web2py and SQLite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web2py

new to web2py and would like to know how I can get a hyperlink to display from the database. I have a page which has a function generating all items from a 'products' database using a for loop to list the name and cost of each product. But I would like to have the name of each product be a hyperlink which will then display all the information (description, weight, actual cost) of the item itself... Have been racking my brain for hours and cant find anywhere how this is possible... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your controller is named `products.py`, in your controller you would have something like:

```
def index():
    products = db(db.product).select()
    return dict(products=products)


def view():
    product_id = request.args(0, cast=int, otherwise=lambda: None)
    product = db(db.product.id == product_id).select().first()
    if product is None:
        raise HTTP(404, 'Cannot find that product')

    return dict(product=product)
```

in your products/index.html view you would have code like this:

```
<ul class="products">
    {{for product in products:}}
    <li>{{=A(product.name,
             _href=URL('products','view', args=[product.id]))}}
    </li>
    {{pass}}
</ul>
```

You might also want to look at the [SQLFORM.grid](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM.grid) which is another way to achieve this depending on what you want to do.